# Convert a function to an OO method

Tags: php, oop

ok, so i have this function. Ive stripped it down to and removed all the html.

```
if($session->power == 'admin'){
    $adminMenu= $user->admin_menu;
     foreach($adminMenu as $key => $value):{ 
        echo $value; echo $key; 
     } endforeach; 
}
```

I am trying to covert this into an OO method, this is my method so far:

**user class**

```
public function get_menu(){
global $session;
$user_status = $session->power;
$adminMenus = $this->admin_menu; // associate array ($key => value)
$menu = array();
if($user_status == 'admin'){
     foreach($adminMenus as $adminMenu):{ 
       $menu = array($adminMenu);
       return array_shift($menu);
     } endforeach;
}
```

**then in the display file**

```
while($user->get_menu()){
echo $user->get_menu();
}
```

I know this is completely wrong - because it doesn't work. So can you please help me make it object orientated.

Comment: You are using `foreach` in a weird way. Like you are combining the normal block style and the alternative syntax. This is very confusing. Just remove the `:` and `endforeach;` (or alternatively the brackets `{}`).

Comment: Also to add to @Felix Kling's comment, this should cause a fatal error: `echo $value echo $key; `, as well as the return in the foreach makes the foreach statement redundant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public function get_menu(){
    global $session;
    $user_status =  $session->power; 
    $adminMenus =$this->admin_menu; // associate array($key => value)
    if($user_status == 'admin')
    { 
      foreach($adminMenus as $key => $value):
      { 
       echo $key . $value;  
      } 
    }
}
```

---

then in the display file

```
$user->get_menu();
```

Comment: at least fix his syntax issues as well :)

Comment: Might I also suggest we get rid of global by passing $session as a parameter somewhere? When I see global in OO code the hair on the back of my neck stands up

Comment: OK this works, however its an associative array so you need loop through the keys and values in the foreach. Can you please explain why you use echo, instead of return??

Comment: @dgamma3: `return` ends the execution of the method right there, so only the first item in the $adminMenus array would be printed. @Alfred: I think the method should be renamed to `print_menu()`.